# How to prove that $f$ is measurable with respect to Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis

Recall that the definition of measurable function as follows.

> If $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space, then $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$ for every Borel set $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

My question is to show that let $(R,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable spaces. Show that every continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{F}$.

---

My proof:

(1) $\Longrightarrow$: assume that continuous functions $f$ is measurable, then by definition for every Borel sets $B\in \mathcal{B}$, $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by open sets $I$, then W.L.O.G. we take $B=I$. [Question: can we assume that?]

Since $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(I)$ is open and $f^{-1}(I)\in \mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing open sets and $\mathcal{B}$ is smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing open sets.

Hence $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{F}$...

(2) For another direction $\Longleftarrow$, assume that $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{F}$.

Since $f$ is continuous, then for every open set $O\subset \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open. Then $f^{-1}(O)\in \mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{F}$.

But how to get that $f$ is measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty standard result that in order to prove that a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, it is sufficient to take a generating set $\mathcal{E}$ of the Borel sigma algebra, and check that the inverse image of every set of $\mathcal{E}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. If we didn't have this result, it would be almost impossible to check whether a function is measurable, because general Borel sets can be extremely complicated. If you haven't seen it yet, here is a hint to the proof. Show that the collection:

$\{B\subseteq\mathbb{R}: f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}\}$

is a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

In particular it follows that if $f^{-1}(O)\in\mathcal{F}$ for any open set $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is measurable.

I didn't understand your proof to the first direction though. It's not even clear what $f$ did you use there. We assume that every continuous function is measurable, and want to show that $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$. Since the Borel sigma algebra is generated by open intervals, it is sufficient to show that $(a,b)\in\mathcal{F}$ whenever $a<b$. Since we know every continuous function is measurable, it is sufficient to present $(a,b)$ in the form $f^{-1}(B)$ for some continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and some Borel set $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Can you find such $f$ and $B$?

Comment: @Hermi Yeah, the identity always works. Actually, I complicated it a bit. We don't even need to go down to working with intervals. Since the identity is measurable, for any Borel set $B$ we have $B=I^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$ where $I:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the identity.

Comment: @Hermi It is enough to check that the inverse image of all the elements in some generating set belong to $\mathcal{F}$. This is a very standard result. Showing that $\{B\subseteq\mathbb{R}: f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is a hint on how to prove that this is indeed sufficient, in case you didn't see it before.

Comment: @Hermi Yes, this is correct. This is enough because sets of the form $(-\infty, b)$ indeed generate the Borel sigma algebra.